# d3 venn diagram labels layering

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Im using this great article to produce a venn diagram with D3.

http://www.benfrederickson.com/venn-diagrams-with-d3.js/

It looks great but on occasion I get bubbles overlapping the the labels become hidden. Is there a way to make sure the text element is always on top? (see the picture below.. label A needs to be on top of circle B.

I found this good article but im struggling in how to implement this in the venn.

[How can I bring a circle to the front with d3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167863/how-can-i-bring-a-circle-to-the-front-with-d3)

[image: layering issue with venn labels]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should grab the latest code from master: this commit should fix the issue you had there https://github.com/benfred/venn.js/commit/4cb3bbef65b5b3c3ce02aee7d913e8814e898baf

Instead of having the 'A' label be overtop of the 'B' circle - it willnow  move the label so that its in the certain of the 'A' region that isn't overlapped with 'B'. Some details are in this issue here: https://github.com/benfred/venn.js/issues/18

Comment: this certainly fixes it - although if you have 3 circles the same size the labels will still overlap

Answer (score 1):

You might find it easier to work in actual layers. You can use `g` elements to create them. For example:

```
var lowerLayer = svg.append('g');
var upperLayer = svg.append('g');
```

Now anything you append to `upperLayer` will appear above anything you append to `lowerLayer` because the two `g` elements have been added to the DOM and are in a specific order.

Also check out [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24050362/1525769) I wrote up for a similar question.